# Xcopy /f /r /y /c exited with code 4 (have tried all solutions found in other answers)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xcopy

So I've been trying to search for a solution to this all morning.  I've checked that all my file paths are in "" without any spaces, I've added /c to the command to ignore errors, I've checked that my folder's aren't in read-only mode (they're not).  Heck I've even added C:\Program Files\WinZip to the System Path Environment Variable.  I'm all out of idea's and nothing so far has worked.  Can anyone think of any other solutions for me to try?

**Here's the full error:**

```
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\Handlers\*.dnn" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\Modules\*.dnn" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\Services\*.dnn" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\bin\Debug\*.dll" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\bin\Debug\*.pdb" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\bin\Debug\*.xml" "C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\_latest\"
```

"C:\Users\bissonk\Desktop\HP\USHC_AMERICAS_US_HC_Ic_Portal\Source\V4.2\Provider\HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI\zip.bat"" 
exited with code 4. HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI

**Here's the zip.bat file:**

```
REM **********************************************************************
REM * HANDLERS
REM **********************************************************************
REM ===========================
REM = Delete Previous File
REM ===========================
del HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Handlers.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Add Files to Zip File
REM ===========================
wzzip -a HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Handlers.zip @..\..\Web.UI.Handlers.files.txt
wzzip -vb HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Handlers.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Copy the Zip File
REM ===========================
 xcopy /d /f /i /r /s /y /c "HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Handlers.zip"     "..\..\_latest\"

REM **********************************************************************
REM * MODULES
REM **********************************************************************
REM ===========================
REM = Delete Previous File
REM ===========================
del HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Modules.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Add Files to Zip File
REM ===========================
wzzip -a HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Modules.zip @..\..\Web.UI.Modules.files.txt
wzzip -vb HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Modules.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Copy the Zip File
REM ===========================
xcopy /d /f /i /r /s /y /c "HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Modules.zip" "..\..\_latest\"


REM **********************************************************************
REM * SKIN OBJECTS
REM **********************************************************************


REM **********************************************************************
REM * SERVICES
REM **********************************************************************
REM ===========================
REM = Delete Previous File
REM ===========================
del HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Services.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Add Files to Zip File
REM ===========================
wzzip -a HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Services.zip @..\..\Web.UI.Services.files.txt
wzzip -vb HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Services.zip

REM ===========================
REM = Copy the Zip File
REM ===========================
xcopy /d /f /i /r /s /y /c "HP.USHC.Portal.Provider.Web.UI.Services.zip"   "..\..\_latest\"
```

**Here's the Post-build Event Command Line**

```
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)Handlers\*.dnn" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)Modules\*.dnn" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)Services\*.dnn" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.dll" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.pdb" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
xcopy /f /r /y /c "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.xml" "$(ProjectDir)_latest\"
"$(ProjectDir)zip.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to invalid directory path in XCOPY command or length of directory path in XCOPY command is above allowed limit.

In my case there was white space in one of the folder name mentioned in directory path. When removed white space in folder name , it worked.

Also this error occurs when you are building application (eg: any windows application) when it is already opened and it refers to dll in the XCOPY command. IN such case close the application and try build again. It will work